# .Net Calendar Event Web Control or Event CMS?

Tags: .net, calendar

I need a calendar control that I can then add events to and drill down into each event. Since it's an Active Directory shop, I can't really utilize Google Calendar or any third-party service which, according to my Google searches, seems to not return anything that meets my requirements (jQuery FullCalendar, etc.).

Am I making this too difficult? Is there a way to use something like the SharePoint Calendar web part to display events? Is there a way to get an Outlook Calendar to publish to a web page?

Comment: Have your considered the jQuery Week Calendar? http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html There is another version thats easier to customize here https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

Comment: Robert - thank you so much for your reply. I did see this and it's my error for not stating earlier, but I do need a Month/Week/Day view for this control. Unless I am missing something, this only displays a single week at a time.

Comment: see the one on github, it has month/week/day views

Answer (score 1):

Check [dhtmlx scheduler.net](http://scheduler-net.com/) - it is standalone events calendar, which can be used without any third-party services.

Comment: Thank you Aquatic. If I don't find anything free that works, I will definitely explore this option as I would need the Enterprise license. Thank you again.